# Advice for specific bootstrap layouts

Tags: mobile, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, desktop

I have a layout in mind that I'd like to look like this on a desktop monitor.  It more or less works right now but I wonder if the 'D' and 'E' sections should be col-md-6 or col-md-3?
[Desktop Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngcwu.png)

Also, (and this is where it gets interesting), on mobile I'd like it to be layed out like this:
[Mobile Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJyJi.png)

Can one single layout work?  I'm busy on the desktop layout but, yeah, everytime I switch to the mobile view things are not good.  Therefore, I have a feeling my initial approach leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution code: 
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               <section class="box">B</section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
               <section class="box">D</section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
               <section class="box">E</section>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
         <section class="box">A</section>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
         <section class="box">C</section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <section class="box">F</section>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <section class="box">G</section>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Arjun but that doesn't look anything like the pictures I uploaded.  Perhaps I'm missing something?